# MySQL get_lock timeout misunderstanding?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, locking

Am I missing something here. I'm looking at using `GET_LOCK` to allow two applications to co-ordinate which data to wok on.

From reading the manual it suggests that I need to apply a timeout to the `GET_LOCK` command.

e.g.

```
SELECT GET_LOCK('testlock1',10);
```

So I'm thinking that this means I am creating a lock called `testlock1` that will remain in place until either I release it, or 10 seconds has passed.

If I then open another session (simulating a second application), and try to run `SELECT GET_LOCK('testlock1',10);` it just returns a `0`.

No matter how long I leave it, the lock remains in place.

I would presume the full process would be something like:

```
SET @id = "SELECT id from dbname.tablename WHERE . . . "
SELECT GET_LOCK(CONCAT(@id,'-dbname-tablename'),10); 
# DO STUFF HERE . . .
UPDATE dbname.tablename . . . WHERE id = @id;
RELEASE GET_LOCK(CONCAT(@id,'-dbname-tablename'));
```

But if something happens, and the `RELEASE_LOCK` doesn't run (and the session remains open), that row will, in essence, be locked from any further updates.
Hence the reason I presumed the timeout was there?

Comment: if you what the LOCK your tables you are on the wrong way.. You really should use the database engine InnoDB with transactions.

Comment: I don't want to lock the tables. Other applications etc will also need to be able to access them at the same time. This is purely about allowing two applications to run simultaneously without the risk of working on the same piece of data and not making the same update twice, which is what I thought the `GET_LOCK` was for.

Answer (score 2):

The timeout applies to how long GET_LOCK will wait to acquire the lock (before timing out), in the event the lock is already held by another client.   It does not indicate how long a LOCK will be held as you mention

Answer (score 0):

About the only use for `GET_LOCK` is for coordination that needs to survive for more than a few seconds.  Otherwise, InnoDB's transactions is a much better way to prevent collisions, especially at the row level.

Something like this is what you are looking for:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
do stuff, including modification of the row(s) SELECTed
COMMIT;
```

And check for errors at each step.  "Deadlocks" can happen in unexpected ways.  If you get a deadlock error, start over at the `BEGIN`.